# Circuitikz american inductor with core

Tags: circuitikz

Using circuitikz I am trying to get an *americaninductor* with a line next to it representing a core. Or said differently, I want something like a *cute choke* but with the coil looking like an americaninductor (semi-circles).  Something like the second inductor (FeSi Core inductor) [image]

Is this possible? My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[europeanresistors,americaninductors]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
 \draw (0,-2)node[left] {} to  [short,o-] (0,0)
 to [short,-*] (1,0);
 \draw [thick](1,0)-- +(30:0.89);
 \draw (1.9,0) to[short,*-*](3,0)
 to [resistor](3,-3)
 to [lamp](3,-4)
 to [short,-*](3,-5)
 to (0,-5)
 to [short,-o] (0,-3);
 
 \draw (3,0) to (5,0)
 to [L] (5,-3)
 to [lamp](5,-4)
 to (5,-5)
 to (3,-5);
\end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: is this what u want -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530609/how-to-draw-a-3-phase-transformer-in-circuitikz

Comment: @jsbibra Not sure what I am looking at, but I guess not. I want an americaninductor (coil represented by semicircles) with a line next to it. I added a picture.

Comment: wheres the picture

Comment: @jsbibra pic should be there now

Comment: If you move the label to the opposite side, you will have plenty of room to add lines.  The solenoid is trickier, but doable (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/584424/draw-transformer-circuitikz/584429?r=SearchResults&s=2|0.0000#584429)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should have happened before or after... ok, if you look at the manual, current version, page 45:

[image]

and the rationale is... I don't know. Probably it could be a reasonable feature request for the package, please feel free to add it. I will have a look to see if it's difficult to incorporate.

From now you can just add the line *after-the-fact*:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
    \draw (0,1) to [cute choke=$L_1$] ++(3,0);
    \draw (0,0) to [american inductor=$L_2$, name=l] ++(3,0);
    \draw [thick]([yshift=1pt]l.north west) -- ([yshift=1pt]l.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since v1.3.3 (not yet released on 2021-04-01) [you will be able to use](https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/pull/507)

```latex
\draw (0,0) to [american inductor=$L_2$, name=l] ++(3,0);
\draw [thick](l.core west) -- (l.core east);
```

so you will have no problems with rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ?

[image]

In this case, use `to [cute choke] (5, -3)` instead of `to [L] (5, -3)`

With the option twolineschoke like `to [cute choke, twolineschoke ] (5, -3)` you obtain

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately not what I am looking for. I added a picture to my question.